# How to extract cell value without brackets in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script in google spread sheet, I have an array of values, but it includes the brackets [], I need to read the value only in a variable without the brackets.

in the code below test gets the value as [" whatever"], I need test to equal "whatever" without brackets

```
function Results() {

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pred = activeSheet.getSheetByName("Copy of Predictions");
  var real = activeSheet.getSheetByName("16 Results");


  var realRes = real.getRange("B7:B61");
  var realVal = realRes.getValues();

  var cell, cellValue, row, col, predVal, predRes, test;

  for(col=2;col<16;col++){
    predRes = pred.getRange(7, col, realVal.length);
    predVal = predRes.getValues();

    for(row=0;row<predVal.length;row++){
      test = predVal[row];      
      if(predVal[row] == ""){
        continue;
      }else if(typeof test === 'string'){
        continue;
      }else{
        if((predVal[row][0] == realVal[row][0]) && (predVal[row+1][0] == realVal[row+1][0])){
          cell = pred.getRange(col, 3);
          cellValue = cell.getValue();
          cell.setValue(cellValue + 15);
        }else{
          if(((predVal[row][0] - predVal[row+1][0]) < 0) && ((realVal[row][0] - realVal[row+1][0]) < 0)){
            cell = pred.getRange('B3');
            cellValue = cell.getValue();
            cell.setValue(cellValue + 5);
          }else if(((predVal[row][0] - predVal[row+1][0]) > 0) && ((realVal[row][0] - realVal[row+1][0]) > 0)){
            cell = pred.getRange('B3');
            cellValue = cell.getValue();
            cell.setValue(cellValue + 5);    
          }else if(((predVal[row][0] - predVal[row+1][0]) == 0) && ((realVal[row][0] - realVal[row+1][0]) == 0)){
            cell = pred.getRange('B3');
            cellValue = cell.getValue();
            cell.setValue(cellValue + 5);    
          }
        }
        row++;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you see square brackets is that getValues() returns an array of arrays, so you are seeing an array with a single value in it.

```
test = predVal[row][0];
```

will get you the value of the first cell in "row".